# Using userform vbmodeless in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, class, userform

I refer to this:
[How to have VBA code wait until vbModeless userform is closed](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1275808)

I tried to apply the code in a class module for my problem.

Problem description:
I have  a userform to insert data, mostly fill text in textboxes.
This userform is opened if incorrect data are found in an Excel table.

I run through the rows of the sheet with a For loop.
When it finds incorrect data it opens the userform to input data manually to textboxes.
With Save and Exit (unload me). I save the data to the sheet.

The reason I use the userform vbmodeless is that I want to copy data from another Excel sheet.
This is not possible if I open the userform vbmodal.

Here is an example of the code:

```vb
Option Explicit
Public done As Boolean 'Userform UF_Input filled

Sub Userform_vbmodeless_in_Loop()
'Testprogram with userform vbmodeless in a loop
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 4
    UF_Input.TextBox1.Text = "That is the " & i & ". Test"
    
    done = False 'per default
    
    'Loop as long as the input userform is not left
    Do While done = False
        UF_Event.Show vbModeless
        DoEvents
        UF_Event.Label1.Caption = "Loop: " & i
    Loop
    
    'Unload Event userform
    Unload UF_Event
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You could have your validation routine going in a separate sub, and set the Visible property of the userform to True in the error handling, where you'd then input the corrected version of the data and overwrite the offending field. Am I understanding this correctly? Also, because you're copying data from another sheet, are you also building that into the program, or doing that manually?